# C++20 format sys_time with milliseconds precision

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono, fmt

I'm trying to write a time string with a millisecond precision in MSVC 19.11 with /stc:c++latest.

With this i get 7 digits accuracy, what i don't want.

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::cout << std::format("{0:%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S}", now);
```

I tried  `std::cout << std::format("{0:%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.3}", now);` and some possibilities of `std::setprecision(3)` in vain.

Is there a solution to format it there or do i need to change "`now`"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
auto now = std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
std::cout << std::format("{0:%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S}", now);
```

or:

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::cout << std::format("{0:%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S}", std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now));
```

I.e. the precision of the output is controlled by the precision of the input.

Aside:  You can also use `%T` in place of `%H:%M:%S` if desired.